# When is leniency allowed in treating sick people on Shabbat or Yom Tov?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, choleh-sick

Fourteen Israeli Sephardic rabbis [have ruled](https://www.timesofisrael.com/sephardic-orthodox-rabbis-say-passover-seder-can-be-held-via-videoconference/) that video-seders are acceptable during a pandemic.  They based their ruling on the fact that halacha allows treating sick people on Shabbat even if their illness is not life-threatening.

My question is: How far can you go in treating non-life-threatening illnesses on Shabbat or Yom Tov?  Must there be pain involved?  Just discomfort?  Psychological too?  What are the limits?  I would like to see a halachic discussion of where to place the dividing line.

(No need to downvote if you disagree with the ruling.  That is not my question.)

Comment: That link is from a year ago...

Comment: You asked about this last year https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/112226/759

Comment: @DoubleAA -- Oops!  Getting old...  But my question is different from a year ago.

Comment: There are multiple books that deal with the topic of medicine and Shabbos.