# Any Halachic problems with app publishing?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, internet, phone, loshon-hara

I'm currently in the process of developing a mobile app, that, be'h will have various Israel related feeds. I was wondering if there could be any Halachic issues with respect to including news feeds from the likes of The Jerusalem Post that will feature articles written by Jews on Shabbos.

Also, occasionally, articles have Loshon Hora issues + promote ideas against halacha. Bearing this in mind, would it be permissible to include these news organizations?

Are there any Halachic issues insofar as making my app available to the general public, which would thus inevitably include Jewish people who would use it on Shabbos r’l.
(Lifnei Iver or Mesayeia/Mesayeia Ledavar Aveira comes to mind).

Comment: Lifnei iver is more limited than that, so you don't need to worry about people using it on shabbos, etc.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of what title would unite the questions here, but you might get more responses if your title relates more closely to your questions.

Comment: I personally don't think based on my study of Lifne Iwer that it would be Asur but I'll have to re-check the sources.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10389/5

Answer (score -4):

As far as I understand, you cannot tell if someone wrote an article on Shabbos. And even if they did, G-d forbid, remember that one of the major lessons of Torah is to judge people favorably. And it would surely be impossible to anyone transgress Shabbos if they truly knew its importance and were fully conscient of their role in Hashem's creation!

Consult your Rabbi for a more complete and more reliable answer!