# Online advertising on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat

I'm about to start an advertising campaign on Twitter and was wondering if there is a problem with my campaign running over Shabbos.

Any thoughts...

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30919/2 and everything linked in the comments there.

Comment: Closely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10358