# Is Mi Yodeya allowed to tweet on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, stackexchange, lifnei-iver, social-media

I recently signed up for [@StackJudaism tweets](https://twitter.com/stackjudaism), just to see what's going on here when not logged in. These tweets are automatically sent out by the Stack Exchange, which [is done for every SE site](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/twitter-question-feeds-for-stack-exchange/).
There is a [second twitter account for this site](https://twitter.com/mi_yodeya), that I discovered through the comments; this account is [run by people](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/956/what-is-the-difference-between-twitter-accounts/957#957). (signed up for this one too!;)
After Shabbos ended last week, I found a number of messages on my phone, tweets from Mi Yodeya. This got me thinking about the permissibility of tweeting on Shabbos, both in and of itself, as well as if these messages could lead to someone being mechallel Shabbos.

---

**In short,** there are three questions here:

1. May one have his computer do something for him on Shabbos? (Dealt with [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10358/may-one-use-a-computer-script-to-do-something-specifically-on-shabbos-yom-tov))
2. Assuming that the actual tweeting is not an issue, is tweeting interesting questions that may lead someone to access the Internet a problem of *lifnei iver*? (see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30919/tweeting-close-to-shabbos))
3. Because of *lifnei iver*, would someone (the moderators? the founder?) have to stop SE's robot account?

Comment: I posit that you won't see the tweets unless you're already accessing the internet *anyway*, so what's the issue?

Comment: @TRiG it is the question of the tweets being set up when it is not Shabbos where the tweeter is but Shabbos where you are, is the acceptance by your server (or transmission to your account) a problem even though **you are not logged in**. This makes the assumption that neither **person** is violating Shabbos. However, the OP also asks what if the recipient does violate Shabbos, does the sender violate lifnei iver?

Comment: FWIW, the twitter account you linked to, StackJudaism, is an SE-programmed robot which the Mi Yodeya community has no direct control of, unlike the mi_yodeya twitter account, which is controlled by community members. See http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/957

Comment: I recommend that you edit your question so that it focuses specifically on the aspect that is *not* addressed by existing questions.

Comment: @TRiG What if I set up a Twitter integration with device (loudspeaker, marquis or monitor) that broadcasts particular tweets in real time, say a billboard in Times Square or an automated speaker somewhere?

Comment: @TRiG What about Twitter text messages? There, he isn't on the Internet to begin with

Comment: @IsaacMoses I didn't know about the second twitter account ... maybe I'll edit in 1 question about mi_yodeya's people account, and a second about if Mi Yodeya needs to stop SE's robot

Comment: @IsaacMoses Better?

Comment: @Shokhet, Instead of listing three questions co-equally and noting that some are dealt with elsewhere here, please make this focus on one clear unaddressed question, and relegate other discussion and references to supporting text. Make it very clear what one question answers to this post are supposed to answer.

Comment: @IsaacMoses K...don't have time now, hopefully will be able to fix this soon-ish